# Delete first row in 2 sheets in a new created workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a macro that copies two sheets and pastes them into a new workbook.

```
Sub Export_File()
Dim Wb3 As Workbook
Dim Wb4 As Workbook
Dim strSaveName As String

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 9) = "Master BO" Then
        Set Wb3 = wB
        Exit For
    End If
Next

strSaveName = Worksheets("Communication").Range("a2").Value

 ' copy sheets to new workbook
Sheets(Array("Auswertung", "Communication")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strSaveName
Set Wb4 = ThisWorkbook

End Sub
```

Everything works - but now I want that the macro deletes the first row of both sheets **in the new workbook**.

The reason I want to delete the first rows is because I have a navigation-bar in the file I copied from.

Hope someone can help me.

Greetings

Comment: ~wb4.Worksheets("Auswertung").Rows("1:2").Delete ~ After Set wb4 = ThisWorkbook. Add similiar another ine for Sheet("Communication")

Comment: Sorry typo it should have been ~Rows("1:1")~

Comment: Okay now I realize that I need another solution because if I delete the row, everything moves in the wrong position. Clearcontents does not clear the buttons (shape elements) in the ROW (I already set it to Move and size with cells). Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Shapes are shape range objects. You make an extra copy of your workbook and then use this line ~ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Delete~ If there are more than one shape then you will have to use their index numbers like Shapes(2), Shapes(3) e.t.c. If this is successful you can incorporate in your main code. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Export_File()
Dim Wb3 As Workbook
Dim Wb4 As Workbook
Dim strSaveName As String

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 9) = "Master BO" Then
        Set Wb3 = wB
        Exit For
    End If
Next

strSaveName = Worksheets("Communication").Range("a2").Value

 ' copy sheets to new workbook
Sheets(Array("Auswertung", "Communication")).Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Auswertung").Rows(1).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Communication").Rows(1).Delete

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strSaveName
Set Wb4 = ThisWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay now I realize that I need another solution because if I delete the row, everything moves in the wrong position. Clearcontents does not clear the buttons (shape elements) in the ROW (I already set it to Move and size with cells). Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Just duplicate the delete row command and change delete to insert.  So that after deletion 1 row will get added.